# SDL_Image libpng error: Not a PNG file

Tags: c++, libpng, sdl-2

I tried to load a png image using SDL_Image:

The code

```
int fname_len = 1024;
char fname[fname_len];
string pwd = getcwd(fname,fname_len);

strcat(fname,"/i/avatar.png");
struct stat buf;
if(stat(fname, &buf)) error("File does not exists",fname);

SDL_RWops *rwop = SDL_RWFromFile(fname, "rb");

SDL_Surface *img = 0;
img = IMG_LoadPNG_RW(rwop); // 6
if(!img) error("Failed to load",fname);

SDL_Texture *tx = tex[z] = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, img); // 5
SDL_FreeSurface(img); // ~6
if(!tx) error("Failed to create texture from",fname);
```

The project file

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL_image
```

When i run it, it shows an error:

```
Failed to load '/tmp/mygame/i/avatar.png': Error reading the PNG file.
libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

when it try to run `file` command, it does exists:

```
# file /tmp/mygame/i/avatar.png
/tmp/mygame/i/avatar.png: PNG image data, 34 x 24, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

the result of `ldd` command are:

```
# ldd /tmp/mygame/mygame
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe9400000)
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0dd39b0000)
    libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 (0x00007f0dd3790000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0dd3488000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0dd3270000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0dd2ec8000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0dd2bc0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0dd29b8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0dd2798000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0dd2590000)
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0x00007f0dd22f8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0dd3c98000)
```

installed and installable libpng* library on my computer:

```
1 extra/libpng 1.6.9-1 [installed]
2 community/libpng12 1.2.50-4 [installed]
3 multilib/lib32-libpng 1.6.8-1 [installed]
4 multilib/lib32-libpng12 1.2.50-2 [installed]
5 catalyst/libpng12 1.2.50-1
6 aur/devkitppc-portlibs-libpng 1.5.4-2 (6)
7 aur/k3d-libpng.patch 0.8.0.1-1 (2)
8 aur/lib32-libpng14 1.4.12-1 (93)
9 aur/lib32-libpng15 1.5.18-1 (34)
10 aur/libpng-old 1.0.2-2 (8)
11 aur/libpng14 1.4.13-2 [installed] (251)
12 aur/libpng15 1.5.18-1 (121)
```

Which part did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post the image file, or replace it with something else? Maybe the header is good enough for file to identify it, but the image body is corrupted so it can't be fully loaded.

Comment: Why are you linking against `SDL2` and `SDL_image`? Shouldn't you be linking against `SDL2_image` instead?

Comment: yes, i've tried to re-save it using GIMP, but still no luck

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/656272/avatar1.png http://wikisend.com/download/233026/avatar.png (valid for 7 days)

Comment: @congusbongus ahhh you solve my problem ^^ thank you!!!

Comment: @congusbongus could you post an answer, i will upvote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converted from a comment:

The problem is that you have linked against `SDL2` and `SDL_image`. The latter is the [1.2 version of the library](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release-1.2.html), meant to be compatible with [SDL 1.2](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php).

When using [SDL2](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage), always use the SDL2 versions of its libraries, e.g. [SDL2_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), [SDL2_mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) and so on.